# angular snapshot test with jest partial match

Tags: angular, jestjs

I'm using jesto to do a snapshot test of an angular component.  The problem is that the one of the fields generated contains a random string generated by a third party component.  The snapshot looks something like this (I'm showing part of it only)

```
                       <input
                          aria-expanded="false"
                          autocapitalize="off"
                          autocomplete="ae8412c06e73"
                          autocorrect="off"
                          readonly=""
                          role="combobox"
                          type="text"
                        />
```

as you can see `autocomplete` is a random string generated by the third party component.  How do I use jest to do a partial snapshot test of this attribute for the angular component.  I know there is something called partial matches in `jest` but not sure how to use it with Angular, since the method signature is quite complicated in terms os specifying the exact attribute.